# Cambiar margin-left segun las coordenadas donde has pinchado

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Quiero que al pinchar en la pantalla me coja las coordenadas y esas coordenadas se coloque como valor para el margin-left.
este es mi código javascript.

```
function coordenadas(event) {
 x=event.clientX;
 y=event.clientY;
 document.getElementById("#img").style.marginLeft=x;
 alert("X: "+x+"px Y: "+y);

}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que según donde tengas el cursor se le añada un margin left a tu imagen?

Comment: si por ejemplo al pinchar me sale 400 en el alert que tengo puesto pues el margin left sea 400.

Comment: he publicado una respuesta, dale un vistazo, espero te sea útil

Answer (score 3):

Creo que esto es lo que quieres

```js
var cat = document.getElementById('img');

function showCoords(event) {
  cat.style.marginLeft = event.clientX + 'px';
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

#img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="showCoords(event)">
  <img id="img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: si exactamente pero la función sería onclick.Voy a probar.

Comment: Listo, he editado mi respuesta, revisala de nuevo :D !

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: @BorjaSanchez recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta ;) ambos ganais rep

Answer (score 2):

Podrias hacer lo siguiente:

- Posicionar absolutamente la imagen (`eg: position: absolute`).
- Suscribirte al evento `click` del `document` para obtener las coordenadas
- Establecer el `margin-left` respecto de la `coord X`

Ejemplo:

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image');
document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  // Coord X - Margen izq
  img.style.marginLeft = evt.clientX + 'px';
  // Coord Y - Margen top y sumamos la mitad de la altura de la imagen
  img.style.marginTop = evt.clientY + (img.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px';
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  top: -25px;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/17/17264.svg" />
```

Comment: No sé si es problema solamente mío pero no se me ejecuta nada en tu snippet :c

Comment: Si, pero no pasa nada, probaré desde firefox a ver

Comment: google chrome desde ubuntu

Comment: desde el firefox funciona y el chromium también, jaja, es raro, deben ser cookies, cache o algo por estilo

Comment: raro, o a lo mejor el `https` en el src de la imagen...

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tienes para que con el click se mueva.

Cambia el div por tu imagen.

Recoge la posicion del raton con el evento click y lo asigna al estilo del elemento, imagen en tu caso.

```js
var mouseX = 0, 
    follower = document.getElementById("follower");


document.onclick = function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;

   follower.style.marginLeft = mouseX + 'px';
};
```

```css
#follower{
  position : absolute;
  background-color : red;
  color : white;
  padding : 10px;
}

body{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="follower">Imagen</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno me parece que lo que tienes ya es suficiente, agrego lo que hace falta para que lo veas funcional. Basta con agregar el event listener y ajustar el margin left en pixels con el valor deseado.

```js
(function(window){
  window.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    var x=event.clientX,
        y=event.clientY;
        img = document.getElementById("img").style.marginLeft=x + "px";
  });  

})(window);
```

```css
img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://assets.entrepreneur.com/content/16x9/822/20141230193127-work.jpeg" alt="dev">
```

Comment: Hola julian, te recomiendo usar el snippet de js incluido en las preguntas y asi te ahorras el ir a otro servicio de snippets online hehe